# How to properly update state with Firebase and useEffect()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch data from Firebase and then push it into my state. The goal is to create a mechanism that will do that every time data in Firebase changes.

I used `on()` method along with `useEffect()`. Unfortunately, React is not re-rendering my component even when the state changes. (ignore direct reference, it's just for testing)

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchedTasks = [];
        const ref = props.firebase.db.ref('users/1zfRCHmD4MVjJj7L884LL4TMwAH3');
        const listener = ref.on('value', snapshot => {
            snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                const key = childSnapshot.key;
                const data = childSnapshot.val();
                fetchedTasks.push({ id: key, ...data });
            });
            setTasks(fetchedTasks);
        });
        return () => ref.off('value', listener);
    }, []);
```

At this point, when I change my data manually in Firebase Console, I can see in my Dev Tools that it triggers the listener, data is fetched, but it's merged with the previous state (tasks).

I want it to replace the previous state of course. Secondly, the component is not re-rendering. I know that the empty dependency list is responsible for that ("[]") and the component mounts only once, but when I remove the list, the component is updating and quickly freezes my browser. I also tried `"[tasks]"` and the result is similar - the component is re-rendering over and over again. Firebase is provided by the context and ESLint displays this:

> "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props.firebase.db'. Either include it or remove the dependency array."

When I do this, it's still not working and the component isn't updating.

Comment: I think the reason why it's being merged is that you only create the `fetchedTasks` array once onMount. After that, every time you say `fetchedTasks.push(..)` you add to the same array. So the list just gets longer and longer. You probably want to either reset `fetchedTasks ` every time you get the values, or, use `.map` instead of `forEach` and then call `setTasks` with the return value of `.map`

Comment: Thanks so much! That actually solved my problem! You gave me a great hint. I looked at my code once again and quickly realized that `fetchedTasks` should be declared directly in a snapshot callback function. Then I put `props.firebase.db` in dependency list. Everything updated and no performance issues!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As my comment solved the issue, here's the official answer:

The reason your state is always merged, is that your variable `fetchedTasks` is only declared once when the hook `useEffect` runs onMount. After that, every time your firebase database updates new values and you call `fetchedTasks.push(...)`, you are pushing on the same "old" array. Therefore your list is getting longer and longer.

One solution would be to just re-declare `fetchedTasks`, or set it back to an empty arry.

```js
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const ref = props.firebase.db.ref('users/1zfRCHmD4MVjJj7L884LL4TMwAH3');
        const listener = ref.on('value', snapshot => {
            const fetchedTasks = [];
            snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                const key = childSnapshot.key;
                const data = childSnapshot.val();
                fetchedTasks.push({ id: key, ...data });
            });
            setTasks(fetchedTasks);
        });
        return () => ref.off('value', listener);
    }, [props.firebase.db]);
```

Another one would be to use `.map` instead, and use the return value for `setTasks`. I think this would be my preferred one:

```js
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const ref = props.firebase.db.ref('users/1zfRCHmD4MVjJj7L884LL4TMwAH3');
        const listener = ref.on('value', snapshot => {
            const fetchedTasks = snapshot.map(childSnapshot => {
                const key = childSnapshot.key;
                const data = childSnapshot.val();
                return { id: key, ...data };
            });
            setTasks(fetchedTasks);
        });
        return () => ref.off('value', listener);
    }, [props.firebase.db]);
```

aso note, that you'd have to pass `props.firebase.db` to your dependency array, to get rid of the eslint warning. The reference to `props.firebase.db` should never change, so it should be save to declare it in the dependency array.