# How to correctly clean up function when fetching Firebase database() on()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I am getting the error below. I assume this is because I'm still subscribed to the Firebase database even when my component unmounts. I am trying to take advantage of the real-time features so that whenever an item is deleted from the list it will reflect on the UI.

[image]

I have created multiple functions with a single purpose to fetch different documents. Below is one example.

```js
export const getAllTask = (userId) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const db = database.ref('tasks');

    db.child(`${userId}/taskItems`).on('value', (snapshot) => {
      const user = snapshot.val();
      if (user) {
        resolve(user);
      } else {
        reject(user);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Then whenever any of my components, it runs my useEffect to fetch data however when it unmounts how can I correctly use `off()` or clean up correctly? Is there a better approach to do this?

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const test = async (userId) => {
    await getAllTask(userId).then((result) => {
      setItems(result);
    });
  };
  test(userId);
}, [userId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ,useEffect returns a function that is called when component unmounts

```
useEffect(() => {
     let mounted=true;
    const test = async (userId) => {
       await getAllTask(userId).then((result) => {
         if(mounted) setItems(result)
      });
    };
   test(userId);
   return ()=>{mounted=false}
  }, [userId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you shouldn't use `on()` at all.  Use `once()` for [reading data a single time](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once).  It returns a promise that's easy to work with.  `on()` is for persistent listeners that deliver updates over time every time something changes with the results of the query.

Since promises can only resolve a single time, it doesn't make sense to wrap a persistent listener in a promise.

If you **do** actually want listener updates over time, for as long as the component is mounted, don't wrap it in a promise.  instead, you should instruct your useEffect to unsubscribe the listener by returning a function that it can invoke to shut things down.

See also: [How to properly update state with Firebase and useEffect()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58708542/how-to-properly-update-state-with-firebase-and-useeffect)  In the answer there, see how the useEffect hook returns a function that calls `off()`.

Comment: On component mount, I get all user tasks, and within that component, there is an input field where I can add to this list and it will appear on the component, it is better off to implement from the example you provided?

Comment: I was hoping to create a singular function in which I only pass the path and userId to fetch data. This is why I tried to implement it this way so  its reusable

Comment: As I said, it will be easier for you to use once() instead of on() since it returns a promise.